# Apply updated co-ordinates from parent rotation to children

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, rotation, coordinates

In the code below, I am rotating a selection box (parent) with two children in SVG.

It works fine, however, when the parent (selection box) is removed, the children go back to their original (pre-rotation) co-ordinates.

How can I apply the updated co-ordinates on the children once the parent is removed. I specifically need to maintain the new position of the children in X,Y co-oridinates, i.e. the rotate should be converted to translate, r.g. transform = translate (X , Y) . I only need New x,y for children so that i can 'translate' them to new location.

here is the fiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/rehankhalid/QK8L8/6/

**HTML CODE:-**

```
<button data-action="rotate" onclick="rotateMainRect()">Rotate +5 Angle</button>&nbsp;
<button data-action="rotate" onclick="removeRectRotation()">Remove Selection</button>
<br/>
<svg id="mainSvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="600" height="500">
    <g id="selectedRect">
        <rect id="rectangle" x="135" y="135" width="110" height="35" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="grey" opacity="0.4" />
        <g id="button_1" transform="translate(0,0)">
            <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="5" stroke="grey" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
        </g>
        <g id="button_2" transform="translate(0,0)">
            <circle cx="230" cy="150" r="5" stroke="grey" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
   var angle_incr = 5;
   var angle = 0;

   function rotateMainRect() {
       var selectedRect = document.getElementById('selectedRect');
       var rectangle = document.getElementById('rectangle');
       var x = rectangle.getAttribute('x');
       if (x != 0) {
           var centxy = calculateCenterXY(selectedRect);
           angle += angle_incr;
           selectedRect.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + angle + ',' + centxy.x + ',' + centxy.y + ')');
       } else {
           rectangle.setAttribute('x', '135');
           rectangle.setAttribute('y', '135');
           rectangle.setAttribute('width', '110');
           rectangle.setAttribute('height', '35');
       }
   }

   function calculateCenterXY(node) {
       var x = node.getBBox().x + (node.getBBox().width / 2);
       var y = node.getBBox().y + (node.getBBox().height / 2);

       var xy_co = {
           x: x,
           y: y
       };

       return xy_co;

   }

   function removeRectRotation() {
       var selectedRect = document.getElementById('selectedRect');
       selectedRect.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', '');

       var rectangle = document.getElementById('rectangle');


       rectangle.setAttribute('x', '0');
       rectangle.setAttribute('y', '0');
       rectangle.setAttribute('width', '0');
       rectangle.setAttribute('height', '0');


       angle = 0;
   }
```

**- What i Want:-**

First Rotate the selection rectangle to some angle, and then press 'Remove selection'. After Removing the selection, Childrens must be placed at the New postion. (which now, move back to the original position)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can read the absolute positions of the two transformed circles directly using JS, then the answer is no.

You will need to calculate their positions yourself using a bit of trigonometry.